# What's the differences between "int b[][MAXN]" in function argument and definition(C++)

Tags: c++

I have a array `int b[MAXN][MAXN];`

When I use `int a[][MAXN] = b;` (I know that `int (*a)[MAXN]` is OK)
It gives me an error.

But If I have a function `void f(int a[][MAXN])`
When I call `f(b);`
It works!

Does someone can tell me why?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: Does this thing only appear in the function argument?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/489590

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry about duplicating. But I don't know it is called "array decaying", so I can't find that solution before :(

Answer (score 1):

When declaring function parameters, `T[]` is treated the same as `T*`, i.e. it declares the parameter as a pointer. So `void f(int a[][MAXN])` simply declares the parameter `a` to be a pointer to  `int` arrays of size `MAXN`.

For other kinds of variables, it is not the same though. That is when you write `int a[][MAXN] = b`, this declares `a` as an array or arrays, not a pointer to arrays. And that's why that doesn't work (because you can't make arrays "point" to other arrays like that).

Note that this isn't specific to arrays of arrays. It's the same if you compare `void f(int a[])` to `int a[] = b`. In the former case the parameter `a` would simply be an `int` pointer (just as if you had written `int *a`) and in the latter case `a` would be an array and you'd get an error for the same reason as above.

Comment: Note also that OP can assign a as a reference to b, just fine:
 int (& a)[MAXN][MAXN] = b;
It's only aggregate initialization of an array with another that is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize [in declaration] any array variable with another like this:

```
int a[1] = {};
int b[] = a;
```

That's not a *decaying to pointer* situation. You seem to want to declare a new array, which would be a copy of the first one. When passing arrays as function parameters like you have shown, they'll decay to pointers, and you won't be creating a new array.

If, instead, you want a reference, you could do:

```
int a[1] = {};

int (&b)[1] = a;  // first reference
auto &c = a;      // second rerefence
```

If you want to make a copy, then make a copy:

```
int a[1] = { 42 };

int b[1];
decltype(a) c;

std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), b);
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), c);
```